# Negation of a specific string in regular expression

Tags: regex, string, unix, negate

I want to negate the string

> ***.INFO**

How can I do this?

I have tried

```
^(?!.*\*\.INFO).*$
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working?" What language is this in, and can you give a few test strings and some sample code that you've tried it in? It seems to work fine if you plug it in here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Define "negate". Do you mean anything other than exactly `*.INFO`, or anything not *containing* `*.INFO`?

Comment: I am writing this rule in a lex file. The test file look like:  *   \n  *.ABCD   \n *.MNC a=10  \n *.INFO A B C D  \n start.      Now i just want to ignore the strings which starts from *. except *.INFO.  So i need to define a rule which identify all strings starting from *. except *.INFO.  @Bohemian  So i mean anything starting from *. other than exactly *.INFO .

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly correct

```
^(?![*][.]INFO).*$
```

you can test it [here](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: @user2114865 just modified it

Comment: @user2114865 looks like you are right http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your recent comment, this matches anything starting with `*.` except `*.INFO`:

```
\*\.(?!INFO\b)\S+
```

Note that by adding the `\b` to `INFO` this will *match* strings that start with`*.INFO` but are followed by other characters, eg `*.INFOXYZ`

Comment: Maybe your tool doesn't recognise look arounds

Comment: Give more detail about what you're trying to do. For example, maybe you can filter the file list before it goes into your tool

Comment: i am just trying to match some specific pattern from file and then simply generating the list of matched patterns.

Comment: What tool are you using? Grep?